# sql upsert statement- postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

Table

```
id | name | value
0  | apis | apple
```

I want to append **,orange** to this value, value should look something like **apple,orange**

I am trying to execute this query however let's suppose the original value is apple, so I am expecting the final value to be apple,orange but I am getting **orange,orange**. Seems like the EXCLUDED.value is reading from INSERT STATEMENT, how do I get the original value appended by comma and orange **(apple,orange)**

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, name, value)
       VALUES(0, 'apis', 'dummyapi')
ON CONFLICT (id,name)
DO UPDATE set value = EXCLUDED.value || ',dummyapi'
    where my_table.name = 'apis'
      AND my_table.id=0
      AND my_table.value not ilike '%dummyapi%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you're concatenaing the EXCLUDED variable with a string and therefore overwriting the contents of `value`, check this out:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, name, value) VALUES(0, 'apis', 'orange')
ON CONFLICT (id,name)
DO UPDATE set value = my_table.value || ',' || EXCLUDED.VALUE;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e0150e53d0b09a9033842aebf6efc42e)